# REST Webservice -- consume xml payload

Tags: web-services, rest

Can someone show or redirect me a sample rest webservice java code, which consumes a xml payload and uses the xml data? I tried googling but it did not help much, Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so you want to build a service that consumes a xml payload, and then use it's data.

You can use resteasy and jaxb for that. You can find an example [here](http://itsvenkis.blogspot.com/2013/08/resteasy-xml-marshalling-and.html)

The idea is the following: your xml payload has to map to a jaxb annotated object, and resteasy will do the unmarshall operation for you.

```
 @POST
 @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
 public Response postOrder(Order order){
                //Its crime to use System.out.println . Use loggers instead
  System.out.println(order.getDestination());
  return Response.status(200).entity("Received XML").build();
 }
```

In this example, Order is a jaxb annotated class, and when you invoke the service, the xml received will be converted (unmarshall operation) to the order object.

It's all explained in the link!

You can also use Jersey, which is another implementation of JAX-RS spec. Here's a [link](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/) that shows what you are trying to do..

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Hi @coder this one is very simple example. which consumes the xmlpayload.

Following is the class created using JAXB annotation for consuming xml data.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "demo-value-provider")
public class DemoValueProvider {

private int a;
private int b;

@XmlElement(name = "value-of-a")
public int getA() {
    return a;
}

public void setA(int a) {
    this.a = a;
}

@XmlElement(name = "value-of-b")
public int getB() {
    return b;
}

public void setB(int b) {
    this.b = b;
}
```

And this is my webservice endpoint which receive this xml payload as input.

```
@Service("DemoWS")
public class DemoWS {

    private final static String MODULE = "DEMO-WS";

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public int methodWithXmlParameter(DemoValueProvider valueProvider) {
        return valueProvider.getA() + valueProvider.getB();
    }
}
```

input xml payload is:

```
<demo-value-provider>
    <value-of-a>1</value-of-a>
    <value-of-b>2</value-of-b>
</demo-value-provider>
```

you can also produce output in xml payload.

Hope this will help you.